# per-link DNS over TLS setting (NetworkManager + systemd-resolved)

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, wireguard

Ubuntu 20.10. Attempts to fix DNS for a split connection (Wireguard VPN for work and a public link for everything else), have stranded in a NetworkManager+systemd-resolved setup.

A problem is that I need DNS-over-TLS to be disabled for any queries going over the wireguard link (limited to a single domain).

**/etc/systemd/resolved.conf** seems to only allow a global setting. So when I enable DNS over TLS there, it is also active for my wireguard link.

I can manually turn it off for the wireguard link with `resolvectl dnsovertls wg0 no`, but every time systemd-resolved is restarted, it turns back on.

If I understand it correctly, the per-link settings for systemd-resolved are managed by NetworkManager. But NetworkManager's key files (the ones in **/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/**) do not seem to have a setting for dns over tls.

How can I get this setting to persist?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and was able to workaround it by using NetworkManager-dispatcher, which allows to run scripts on connection events.

I'm not sure if will work on Ubuntu since I'm using Fedora, but here is what I've done:

1. Enable NetworkManager-dispatcher.service

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

2. Create script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ directory with following contents:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

readonly interface="$1"
readonly action="$2"

if [[ $action = vpn-up && $CONNECTION_ID = udp-other ]]; then
    resolvectl dnsovertls "$interface" no
fi
```

Replace `udp-other` with name of your VPN connection (or alternatively, you can use `$CONNECTION_UUID`) and make sure that script's owner and group is root and it is marked as executable.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible with the `connection.dns-over-tls` setting, added in  [this commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/commit/b652202829d7cf19b2033476c42e4cb50195958b).

To set the default value for all NetworkManager-managed connections, edit `NetworkManager.conf` to include e.g.:

```ini
[connection]
connection.dns-over-tls=0
```

To set on a single connection, execute:

```
nmcli connection modify MyConnection connection.dns-over-tls 0
```